# Find all words start with vowel (a,e,i,o,u) in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am using this python regex code
`re.findall(r"\b[aeiou]\w*\b", s, re.I)` It works for case `s = "there is an apple"`, but not for `s = "there _is an_apple"`
How do I modify `r"\b[aeiou]\w*\b"` to ignore underscores in a string?

Comment: From the input `there _is an_apple` what exactly are the words you would expect to be matching?

Comment: output should be ['is', 'an', 'apple'], same as the first case

Comment: `...\b", s.replace('_', ''), re.I)`

Comment: But what if I don't want to modify the string?

Comment: How about `re.findall(r"\b_*([aeiou]\w*)\b", s, re.I)`?

Comment: `r"\b_*([aeiou]\w*)\b"` won't work because \b doesn't match after _ but \w does.

Comment: `s.replace()` doesn't modify the string, it makes a new string...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, if the string were `"a_hat"` that would convert it to `"ahat"`, which would be matched, but it's only `"a"` that should be matched.

Comment: When asked for clarification (comment #1, for example), it's always best to edit the question rather than elaborating in a comment. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all comments are read by all readers and comments can be deleted, leaving your replies without context. You also need to define "words" used in the title. We know the words of interest begin with vowels, but what about the remaining characters? Just letters, as in normal text? Digits? It appears they my not contain an underscore, which is a "`\w`-word" character.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - "How do I modify `r"\b[aeiou]\w*\b"` to ignore underscores in a string?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to come up with the following regex pattern:

```
(?:^|(?<=[\W_]))[aeiou][^\W_]*(?=[\s_]|$)
```

This defines a matching "word" as starting with a vowel, and preceded by either whitespace, the start of the input, or an underscore, and also ending with either whitespace, the end of the input, or an underscore.  Sample script:

```
s = "there _is an_apple"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=[\W_]))[aeiou][^\W_]*(?=[\s_]|$)', s, re.I)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['is', 'an', 'apple']
```

The regex pattern used merits a more detailed explanation:

```
(?:^|(?<=[\W_]))  assert that what precedes is either: the start of the input or
                  a non word character, but including underscore
[aeiou]           match a leading vowel
[^\W_]*           then match zero or more word characters, but excluding underscore
(?=[\s_]|$)       assert the end of the word, which is either whitespace, underscore, or
                  the end of the input
```

Comment: Considering that you used a `(?=[\s_]|$)` after I find it curious that you did not use `(?<=^|[\W_])` before.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Try that in Python and see what happens `:-)` ... Python's regex engine doesn't allow non fixed width lookbehinds, and your suggestion uses an alternation which mixes width-one and width-zero together; not allowed.

Comment: Good point. I often forget that about Python. Some other languages that don't permit variable-length lookbehinds would give that a pass (Ruby, for example). I'll leave my comment, as your reply is instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

`re.findall(r"[^\w]*\w?[aeiou]\w+[^\w]*", s, re.I)`

`[^\w]` - means anything thats not a letter (including spaces and underscores)

as you said you didn't want to change the string.

However, I would recommend just doing string replace of

`s.replace("_", " ")` as it doesn't actually change the s string, it creates a new string in memory.

Comment: This will return `['there ', '_is ', 'an_apple']` for "there _is an_apple", which is not what's wanted?

Comment: He said he didn't want to do string replace, i.e. didn't want to change underscores. You can't do string replace AND regex match in `re.findall`, you either do one or the other

Comment: Yeah; your regex doesn't work. It's possible to make a regex that does, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works:

`re.findall(r"(?<=^|[ _])[aeiou][a-z]*", s, re.I)`

This finds ['is', 'an', 'apple'] for all of "there is an apple", "there _is an_apple" and "is an_apple".

However, it's an ugly regex; in most cases, I'd recommend using the s.replace solution instead:
`re.findall(r"\b[aeiou]\w*\b", s.replace('_', ' '), re.I)`

Comment: I suspect that the OP just wants a regex pattern which can be used with `re.findall` directly on the input, without resorting to doing manual string replacements.

Comment: Indeed; trying to do everything in one step. There are situations where that's necessary, and others where that's elegant; this doesn't appear to be either of those cases.

Comment: Bah, I have the .replace backwards, don't I... Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the examples given in the question I have assumed that words to be matched are comprised of letters (beginning with a vowel). This is despite the regex mentioned by the OP: `r"\b[aeiou]\w*\b"`. If my assumption is incorrect my answer would of course need to be modified accordingly.

I suggest using `re.findall` to match the string with the regular expression

```
r'(?i)(?<![^\W_])[aeiou][a-z]*'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/yAgZQ2/1/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?i)         : set case-indifferent mode
(?<![^\W_]). : use a negative lookbehind to assert that next match is
               not preceded by a character that is not a non-whitespace
               and not an  underscore
[aeiou]      : match a vowel
[a-z]*       : match 0+ letters
```

Notice that `(?<![^\W_])` has the same effect as `(?:^|(?<=[\W_]))` in @Tim's answer. Similarly, `(?=[\s_]|$)` in Tim's answer is equivalent to `(?![^\s_])`. One can use either form.